# Authorization issue when use [Authorize] attribute in page in client blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-client-side

When i use

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

on a razor page in blazor Client app it give me this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
>   'AuthorizationPolicyProvider' on type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.PageDisplay+AuthorizeViewWithSuppliedData'.
>   There is no registered service of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationPolicyProvider'

I set the authentication and use custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` for the client side as following

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<AuthService, AuthService>();
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
```

any help with this issue

Answer (score 14):

i just needed to add `services.AddAuthorizationCore();`

thanks for KodiakMx

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    }
```

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution.

Comment: Funny thing: I had to add this on the client side as well (Even if it was a server side app in my case and it was already added on the server side startup as well?!).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` to your `Configure` method in `Startup` class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: this is a client side app not the server app

Comment: thanks i added  services.AddAuthorizationCore(); and it's working

Comment: @ShinichiKudo Thanks god for the comment... The guys keeps mentioning `services.AddAuthorizationCore()` makes me feel like that they are talking about the Sever app... As the default template is so much different in names...

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

to Program.cs (if you are .NET core hosting, make sure it is Client\Program.cs) for newer projects.